# SQL Found the previous date from another row matching query looking for a little more data now and a 'replace'?

Tags: php, sql, date, replace, null

So m.zam worked out the answer. Thank you very much.
Can anyone take this a little bit further?
Here's the two tables. There are two things I'm trying to do now, replace a returned null date with  the words 'New Song' and I'm trying to find out how many shows have there been since a song was last played.

```
song_id   song_name
  51  |  Song Name A
  368 |  Song Name B
  168 |  Song Name C
  568 |  Song Name D
  13  |  Song Name E


song_id | song_order|        show_date      |show_id
368     |     1     |  2010-02-17 00:00:00  |  367      
368     |     0     |  2012-04-06 00:00:00  |  499 
51      |     2     |  2012-01-19 00:00:00  |  399
51      |     2     |  2013-04-24 00:00:00  |  870 
51      |     8     |  2013-07-19 00:00:00  |  899 
368     |     2     |  2013-07-19 00:00:00  |  899 
13      |     5     |  2013-07-19 00:00:00  |  899 
568     |     2     |  2013-07-19 00:00:00  |  899
368     |     4     |  2012-06-08 00:00:00  |  799 
168     |     2     |  2013-06-28 00:00:00  |  896 
568     |     2     |  2013-07-03 00:00:00  |  897 
568     |     2     |  2010-02-21 00:00:00  |  897
```

My code below is working to return this but I need some more data. I'm looking to turn the first table into the second. Thanks in advanced! Code can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3e29/1

FIRST

```
  SHOW_DATE    | SHOW_ID |   SONG_NAME | SONG_ID |     PREVDATE    |
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name A |      51 | April, 24 2013  |
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name B |     368 | June, 08 2012   |
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name E |      13 | (null)          |
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name D |     568 | July, 03 2013   |
```

SECOND

```
  SHOW_DATE    | SHOW_ID |   SONG_NAME | SONG_ID |     PREVDATE    |  SHOWS SINCE
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name A |      51 | April, 24 2013  |       2
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name B |     368 | June, 08 2012   |       4
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name E |      13 | NEW SONG        |       0
July, 19 2013  |     899 | Song Name D |     568 | July, 03 2013   |       0



   SELECT a.show_date, a.show_id, 
    b.song_name, a.song_id, (
    SELECT
      IFNULL(MAX(show_date),'NEW SONG')
    FROM tbl_shows AS c
   WHERE a.show_date > c.show_date and a.song_id = c.song_id
   ) As PrevDate
   FROM tbl_shows a, tbl_songs b
   WHERE a.song_id = b.song_id
   AND a.show_id = 899
```

Though IFNULL works in SQL, im using PHP to change the format of the returned date to something more like mm/dd/yy, could I change the date in SQL before sending it to PHP or write a IF ELSE statement in the PHP to return either mm/dd/yy or 'NEW SONG'

```
  echo "<td style='padding: 10px; width:45px;'>" .date("m/d/y",   
   strtotime($row["PrevDate"]))." </td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for the first part (NEW SONG)**

```
 SELECT a.show_date, a.show_id, 
  b.song_name, a.song_id, 
 (
  SELECT IFNULL(MAX(show_date),'NEW SONG')
  FROM tbl_shows AS c
  WHERE a.show_date > c.show_date and a.song_id = c.song_id
  ) As PrevDate
  FROM tbl_shows a, tbl_songs b
  WHERE a.song_id = b.song_id
  AND a.show_id = 899
```

Comment: Thanks Sparky you answer to this part of my question worked... though I've only tested it on SQLFiddle and it works, my server is down so I can't implement it just yet any idea how I can get my second part to count the shows between the one selected, 899 and the last time it was played? show_id should be sequential so it should just be a subtract? but what's the code?

Comment: I spoke to soon, though this does change the null to 'New Song", I had a statement in my php that changed the date format to m/d/yy, that format changes 'New Song' to 01/01/1970, I still want that format for dates but if it was 01/01/1970, I guess this is now more of a php question than sql...thanks. I'll put my php above.